# CI failing with RSpec and Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, rspec, semaphore-ci

we have a rails app and have semaphoreCI running our specs.
In our local machines, all of the specs are passing without any problem at all.

However, we are getting all our specs failing, with failures such as the following:

```
Failures:

  1) HousesController GET #index 
     Got 0 failures and 2 other errors:

     1.1) Failure/Error: Address.reindex

          Faraday::ConnectionFailed:
            Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200)
```

We have been researching and we have found https://semaphoreci.com/docs/elasticsearch.html, meaning that it is already configured so elasticsearch runs automatically.

Could it be a solution to change the default port semaphoreCI uses? How can we do that, if this is the case?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Seems like to connect it required transport_address and not http. So try `localhost:9300`. Note that 9300 is default tcp port which is assigned. It can be different in your case.

Comment: To get `transport_address` use `http://localhost:9200/_nodes?pretty`

Comment: @NishantSaini do you mean that I should try that in the CLI of semaphoreCI?

Comment: I don't know much about that, but there may be somewhere a config/variable where the connection address is currently mention `localhost:9200`